# Convertion from ByteArray to unsigned char*

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, type-conversion, unsigned-char

i'm in Qt and i dhave the following problem: I'm storing a fingerprint template from a embedded system, after sending a command thru ftp, my system get fingerprint from scan and save the template (as unsigned char*) i do know the size of the template, and hes constante (always 384)
the problem is, to send to server thru ftp i need to convert to bytearray, then store it and send it back to the module. I'm able to send, store it and send it back to the module, but when i try to convert the received bytearray back to unsigned char* i'm not able to. (i need to convert it back because to enroll this received fingerprint, the template should be unsigned char*) 
Does anyone know how could i convert from bytearray to unsigned char* ? Really appreciate the attention!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char *QByteArray::data()`
Should be what you looking for

Comment: Or constData(), to prevent QByteArray making a copy (if the QByteArray is not const).